# returning a std::string from a variant which can hold std::string or double

Tags: c++, string, c++17, variant

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using Variant = std::variant<double, std::string>;

// helper type for the visitor
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;


std::string string_from(const Variant& v)
{
    return std::visit(overloaded {
        [](const double arg) { return std::to_string(arg); },
        [](const std::string& arg) { return arg; },
        }, v);
}

int main()
{
    Variant v1 {"Hello"};
    Variant v2 {1.23};
    
    std::cout << string_from(v1) << '\n';
    std::cout << string_from(v2) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I have a function called `string_from()` which takes a variant and converts its inner value to a string.

The variant can hold either a `std::string` or a `double`.

In case of a `std::string`, I just return it.

In case of a `double`, I create a `std::string` from the `double` and then return it.

The problem is, I don't like the fact that I'm returning a copy of the `std::string` in case of a string-variant. Ideally, I would return a `std::string_view` or another kind of string observer.

However, I cannot return a `std::string_view` because in case of a double-variant I need to create a new temporary `std::string` and `std::string_view` is non-owning.

I cannot return a `std::string&` for the same reason.

I'm wondering if there's a way to optimize the code so that I can avoid the copy in case of a string-variant.

Note in my actual use case, I obtain strings from string-variants very frequently, but very rarely from double-variants.

But I still want to be able to obtain a `std::string` from a double-variant.

Also, in my actual use case, I usually just observe the string, so I don't really need the copy every time. `std::string_view` or some other string-observer would be perfect in this case, but it is impossible due to the reasons above.

I've considered several possible solutions, but I don't like any of them:

1. return a `char*` instead of a `std::string` and allocate the c-string somewhere on the heap in case of a `double`. In this case, I would also need to wrap the whole thing in a class which owns the heap-allocated strings to avoid memory leaks.
2. return a `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` with a custom deleter which would cleanup the heap-allocated strings, but would do nothing in case the string resides in the variant. Not sure how this custom deleter would be implemented.
3. Change the variant so it holds a `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` instead. Then when I need a string from the string-variant I just return a copy of the shared_ptr and when I need a string from the double-variant I call `std::make_shared()`.

The third solution has an inherent problem: the `std::string` no longer resides in the variant, which means chasing pointers and losing performance.

Can you propose any other solutions to this problem? Something which performs better than copying a `std::string` every time I call the function.

Comment: do you actually need to store the `double`? Why not always convert the `double` to `std::string` and use a `std::string` instead of the variant?

Comment: Because I use the variant as a common interface for keeping both kinds of values.
In some cases I need doubles, in some cases I need strings.
They are stored in a shared container and their order matters, so I cannot use 2 separate containers.

Comment: Do you really need to return a string, and not just "use" it: `template <typename F> void do_job_with_string(F f, const Variant& v) { std::visit(overloaded { [&](const double arg) { f(std::to_string(arg)); }, [&](const std::string& arg) { f(arg); } }, v);}`

Comment: Keep in mind that creating and copying short strings is already cheap, so if most of your strings are short, there shouldn't be a problem. Technically, you could return a `variant<string, string_view>` (yikes) or return a type containing both a `string` and a `string_view` where you exclusively use the view knowing that the accompanying string can act as backing storage if needed (also kind of yikes). I'm happy to be wrong, but I don't think there's a really clean and direct solution to conditional lifetime in C++.

Comment: Another (ugly) option would be to add a parameter `std::string& buffer` to `string_from` that has to be provided at the call side and `string_from` writes `std::to_string(arg)` to `buffer` in the `double` case. Then you can return either a reference to `buffer` (`double` case) or to the `string` inside the `variant` from `string_from`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I most cases I need the actual string (or a string_view), so I can pass it to other functions in my application. Although, that's a good point. I need to think about it.

Comment: @n314159 In your solution I would need a create a new string every time I call the function. At least I would avoid the unnecessary copy, but I agree it's kind of ugly :)

Comment: So it seems most of the solutions propose creating a backup std::string storage for the `double` case. Either wrapped in the returned type or as an output parameter.

Comment: Return a `variant<string, string_view>` may be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a proxy object. (this is like your `unique_ptr` method)

```
struct view_as_string{
    view_as_string(const std::variant<double, std::string>& v){
        auto s = std::get_if<std::string>(&v);
        if(s) ref = s;
        else temp = std::to_string(std::get<double>(v));
    }
    const std::string& data(){return ref?*ref:temp;}
    const std::string* ref = nullptr;
    std::string temp;
};
```

Use

```
int main()
{
    std::variant<double, std::string> v1 {"Hello"};
    std::variant<double, std::string> v2 {1.23};
    
    std::cout << view_as_string(v1).data() << '\n';
    
    view_as_string v2s(v2);
    std::cout << v2s.data() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, a variant holds different types, but you're trying to find a way to represent all of them in a single type.  A string representation is useful for generic logging, but it has the downsides you describe.

For variants, I don't like trying to consolidate the values back into a single common thing, because if that was easily possible then there would be no need for the variant in the first place.

Better, I think, is to defer the conversion as late as possible, and keep forwarding it on to other functions that make use of the value as it is, or convert and forward until it's used--rather than trying to extract a single value and trying to use that.

A fairly generic function might look like this:

```
template <typename Variant, typename Handler>
auto with_string_view(Variant const & variant, Handler && handler) {
   return std::visit(overloaded{
       [&](auto const & obj) {
           using std::to_string;
           return handler(to_string(obj));
       },
       [&](std::string const & str) {return handler(str); },
       [&](std::string_view str) { return handler(str); },
       [&](char const * str) { return handler(str); }
   }, variant);
}
```

Since the temporary created in the generic version outlives the call to the handler, this is safe and efficient.  It also shows the "forward it on" technique that I've found to be very useful with variants (and visiting in general, even for non-variants.)

Also, I don't explicitly convert to string_view, but the function could add requirements that the handler accepts string views (if that helps document the usage.)

With the above helper function you might use it like this:

```
using V = std::variant<std::string, double>;

V v1{4.567};
V v2{"foo"};

auto print = [](std::string_view sv) { std::cout << sv << "\n";};
with_string_view(v1, print);
with_string_view(v2, print);
```

Here's a full live example, expanded out a little too: https://godbolt.org/z/n7KhEW7vY

Comment: You suggestion seems the best one, however, my application is built around getting the value out of the variant and pass it to other functions or return it, so it would require a lot of changes in my code. That's why I'm not marking this as the accepted solution but I think it's the best one if your haven't written your infrastructure yet.

Answer (score 0):

If thread safety is not an issue, you could simply use a static `std::string` as the backing storage when returning a double value. Then you would be able to return a `std::string_view`, eg:

```cpp
std::string_view string_from(const Variant& v)
{
    static std::string buffer;
    return std::visit(overloaded {
        [&buffer](const double arg) -> std::string_view { buffer = std::to_string(arg); return buffer; },
        [](const std::string& arg) -> std::string_view { return arg; },
        }, v);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/WBgZJzcIt)

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with my own solution inspired by apple apple's solution with the `view_as_string` class.
Here it is:

```
class owning_string_view : public std::string_view
{
public:
    explicit owning_string_view(const char* str) : std::string_view{str}, m_string_buffer{} {}
    explicit owning_string_view(const std::string& str) : std::string_view{str}, m_string_buffer{} {}
    explicit owning_string_view(std::string&& str) : std::string_view{}, m_string_buffer{std::move(str)}
    {
        static_cast<std::string_view&>(*this) = m_string_buffer;
    }

private:
    std::string m_string_buffer;
};
```

Instead of taking a `Variant` I made it more generic and it takes strings instead.
For lvalue strings it just creates a `std::string_view` of the string.
For rvalue strings it moves the string into the buffer.

It extends from `std::string_view` so it can be used in `std::string_view` contexts seamlessly.

Of course you have to be careful not no slice off the `std::string_view` part from the object when creating an rvalue `owning_string_view` but this is true for `std::string_view` as well. You have to be careful not to take a `std::string_view` from an rvalue `std::string`.

Passing a `owning_string_view` as a `std::string_view` parameter to a function is safe for the same reason it is safe to pass an rvalue `std::string` as a `std::string_view` parameter to a function. The rvalue lives during the function call.

I also realized a deeper problem when returning a string_view from my `Variant`class.
If I try to extract a `std::string_view` or a `owning_string_view` from an rvalue `Variant` I'm still going do end up with a dangling string_view, so I added 2 functions for taking a string from the `Variant`:

- one accepts lvalue variants only and it returns `owning_string_view`.
- the other accepts rvalue variants only and it returns a `std::string`, which is moved from the variant (since the variant is an rvalue).

One more observation: Ideally, I would make the first 2 constructors of `owning_string_view` `constexpr` but I can't because the default constructor of `std::string` is not `constexpr`. I hope this is changed in the future.